# Dimensions available for a gang toggle light switch cover

Tags: switch

I have an older home (1960s) and I need a replacement 2 gang toggle switch plate cover.

I cannot find one that measures 4 1/2 inches by 2 3/4 inches. I have found plenty of 1 gang toggle switch covers in this size but no 2 gang.

Ironically, we have wall plate that size in the kitchen, but it's in use. Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance of a picture?  A "2-gang" cover will be 4.5x4.5, so I think you are using "gang" incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah, the word "gang" refers to the space in which one mounts a twin receptacle or a single switch. So for instance a 2-gang box can mount a GFCI receptacle right next to a plain receptacle.  If you have 2 switches in 1 gang, which would  be consistent with the kind of sizes you are stating, then you just use a plain, common-as-dirt double oval cover for receptacles.  If that doesn't get you there,  definitely shoot a photo of the switch, [edit] it into the question, and we'll get you on the right track.

Comment: @harper that should be an answer , the op has. Single gang 2 switch need they are not in common even 3 position at my local platt.

Comment: @EdBeal Yeah but my answer is so obvious that I'm sure they've already looked at that.  I suspect something weird... like a Despard.

Comment: Both of us have had some we thought were put it up I will vote jphi1618 probably will also I think we all had the same thing in mind a standard duplex or oval is normal but I have seen square most are no longer handle style decora style in the same space as a std duplex receptacle.

Comment: Posted an answer - it seems we're all in agreement.  I could have mentioned the Decora style, but I don't think that was around in the 60s.

Comment: I did go back and the 3 pole on 1 gang was decora or despard and despard spacing is different than duplex. Both single gang 2 & 3 switch positions. Jphi1618 I agree but despard was and that is what I thought Harper was talking about 2-3 switches per gang common back then.

Comment: Just because the house was built in the 60s (or earlier) doesn't mean that it's stuck with all original switch gear...

Answer (score 3):

From you measurements, what you have *is* a single gang box.  If you have a duplex switch (two switches stacked on top of each other), then those use the same box cover as a duplex outlet:

[image: Duplex switch] [image: Duplex cover]

If for some reason, a duplex cover does not fit, you must have a very old duplex switch style that isn't made anymore.  In this case, the easiest thing to do is to replace the switch and get a standard cover for it.